# when trying to edit dataset eclipse freeze and doesn't respond

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I am using birt in eclipse to build and run some reports , i have build a report that contain one dataset but whenever i try to edit the dataset (changes inside the query or even refreshing the dataset) eclipse freeze.

any help please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to add -debug to your eclipse.exe. For that create a shortcut and then in the target, add `-debug`, then run the shortcut. 
If you have an error, please add edit your post with the stack.

Comment: @Bob actually i am using a mac , how can i do it?

Comment: Make sure to use the latest version of Eclipse (currently, Oxygen.3a). You can use _Window > Preferences: General > UI Responsiveness Monitoring_ to gather more information about the problem.

Comment: @howlger where can i see the result when it freeze?

Comment: In the log file in your workspace: `<workspace>/.metadata/.log`

Comment: @howlger thank you for your help , i managed to solve my problem it was because of the datasource url

Answer (score 0):

I bet that either your JDBC connection properties are wrong (did you test the connection?) or that your query takes very long.

Note that BIRT has the habit to actually execute the query when you edit it.
It does not fetch the result records, but it executes the query in order to get the description of the result set from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

you should not edit data set for the report . you can change the data set if any element in the dataset is not bound to the report . If it is bound to report then you have to delete those elements from your report which refers to the elements in dataset and you can modify the dataset